# Oracle ORA-04030 even when using Bind Variables in a LOOP

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql

I have to delete almost 500 million rows from a remote table using PL/SQL. Since the UNDO tablespace cannot handle the volume, the deletes are being done in batches size of 1,000,000 and committed. Also - to reduce hard-parsing I am using bind variables using following syntax:

```
str := 'delete from table@link where id >= :x and id < :y';
execute immediate str using start_id, start_id+1000000
```

And after every invocation, the start_id is incremented by 1000000 till SQL%rowcount returns 0 ( zero ) and end_id ( which is known ) is reached.

But the process is getting ORA-0430 as follows:

```
ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 16408 bytes (QERHJ hash-joi,QERHJ Bit vector)

ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 41888 bytes (kxs-heap-c,temporary memory)
```

Note that I am already using bind variables so that there is no hard parsing after first execution.

One thing could be the range of ID at target. Assuming first few rows are in increasing order, the IDs are

```
100,000,000,000
200,000,000,000
50,000,000,000,000,000
50,000,000,000,011,111
```

On second iteration, IDs from 200,000,000,000 to 200,000,100,000 will be deleted.

But since there are no IDs in this range, it will take almost 50,000,000,000 iterations to get to next row ( 50,000,000,000,000,000 / 1000000 = 50,000,000,000  ).

Of course - I can always examine the ID from target and choose correct range ( that is much larger from default 1 million ).

But that should not be the case for process to run out of memory.

**Added Code:**

remote.sql : execute on remote :

```
create table test1
(
    id      number(38) primary key
); 
insert into test1 select level from dual connect by level < 1000000;
insert into test1 values ( 1000000000000 );
insert into test1 values ( 2000000000000 );
commit;
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats ( ownname => user, tabname => 'test1',           
     cascade => true, estimate_percent => 100 );
commit;
```

local.sql :

```
create or replace procedure batch_del
as
     l_min_val       integer;
     l_max_val       integer;
     l_cnt           integer;
     l_cnt_dst       integer;
     l_begin         integer;
     l_end           integer;
     l_str           varchar2(1000);
     l_tot_cnt       integer;
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
  begin
      l_tot_cnt := 0;
      l_str := ' select min(id), max(id), count(*) from test1@dst';
      execute immediate l_str into l_min_val, l_max_val, l_cnt_dst;
      dbms_output.put_line ( 'min: ' || l_min_val || ' max: ' || l_max_val
           || ' total : ' || l_cnt_dst );
      l_begin := l_min_val;
      while l_begin  < l_max_val
      loop
           begin
              l_end := l_begin + 100000;
              delete from test1@dst where id >= l_begin and id < l_end;
              l_cnt := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
              dbms_output.put_line ( 'Rows Processed : ' || l_cnt );
              l_tot_cnt := l_tot_cnt + l_cnt;
              dbms_output.put_line ( 'Rows Processed So Far : ' || l_tot_cnt );
              commit;
          exception
          when others then
               dbms_output.put_line    ( 'Error : ' || sqlcode );
     end;
 l_begin := l_begin + 100000;  
 end loop;
 dbms_output.put_line ( 'Total : ' || l_tot_cnt );
end;
```

**All Local Implementation **

```
drop table test1;
create table test1
(
 id    number(38) primary key
);
insert into test1 select level from dual connect by level < 1000000;
insert into test1 values ( 1000000000000 );
insert into test1 values ( 2000000000000 );
commit;
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats ( ownname => user, tabname => 'test1', 
cascade => true, estimate_percent => 100 );
commit;
create or replace procedure batch_del
as
   l_min_val       integer;
   l_max_val       integer;
   l_cnt           integer;
   l_begin         integer;
   l_tot_cnt       integer;
 pragma autonomous_transaction;
 begin
  l_tot_cnt := 0;
  select min(id), max(id) into l_min_val, l_max_val from test1;
  l_begin := l_min_val;
  while l_begin  < l_max_val
  loop
    begin
     delete from test1 where id >= l_begin and id < l_begin + 10000;
     l_cnt := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
     dbms_output.put_line ( 'Rows Processed : ' || l_cnt );
     l_tot_cnt := l_tot_cnt + l_cnt;
     dbms_output.put_line ( 'Rows Processed So Far : ' || l_tot_cnt );
     commit;
   exception
     when others then
      dbms_output.put_line    ( 'Error : ' || sqlcode );
 end;
 l_begin := l_begin + 10000;
 end loop;
 dbms_output.put_line ( 'Total : ' || l_tot_cnt );
end;  

set timing on;
set serveroutput on size unli;
exec batch_del;
```

Comment: Are there any rows you are **not** deleting?  It would appear not - in which case why not **truncate** the table instead?

Comment: I cannot truncate the table. There are rows I don't want to delete.

Comment: What proportion are you preserving though? It might still be easier to copy those elsewhere, truncate and then copy them back; or CTAS with just the ones you want to keep. Is the table partitioned? Indexed on that key? Can you get the work done on the remote end instead?

Comment: In that case you should seriously consider using `create table x as select ... from y` to create a new table that has just the rows you want.  Then drop the old, rename the new, reinstate constraints, indexes etc.  Deleting half a billion rows is not a nice thing to do.

Comment: Unfortunately this is multi-tenant environment. While a subset of rows is being deleted, other are in use. Hence it does not matters whether 1% of rows are being deleted or 99%. Yes - CTAS will be great but the table is being used by other tenants. No - we cannot use partitioning due to costs. Will doing the work on remote reduce memory requirements ?

Comment: I would definitely want to **try** doing this on the remote database not via a dblink, in case that is the cause of your problem.

Comment: There is no need for you to use dynamic sql for this - you can do the same thing with static sql - i.e. `delete from table@link where id >= start_id and id < start_id+1000000`; that would be even better from a parsing point of view, since dynamic sql needs to be parsed every single time it's called, whereas the static sql doesn't need to be (see [Tom Kyte's answer](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:864237961410) for more details).

Comment: Also, it would help if you could add an example of your code to your question - it doesn't have to have the exact table, column etc names, but it does need to reflect accurately what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Boneist - while I figure out how to attach code, my apprehension seems correct. If the remote table has two consecutive rows with a huge gap in values, the default batch size of 1,000,000 will cause the delete statement into several un-necessary loops till it reaches next value.

Comment: Why do those extra loops matter? The delete statements within them just won't find anything to delete, so - assuming the ID you're using is indexed - they won't add much overhead. Do you have a reason to think they are related to the error you're getting?

Comment: I definitely wouldn't be running 500mm deletes over a db link.  Wonder why your DBAs aren't flipping out to be honest.

Comment: I have added code. If my remote table has to consecutive records with huge difference, then stored proc executed from local takes forever. If the two records are not there - then the stored proc finishes in < 30 seconds. So - it seems the extra loops do matter.

Comment: @AlexPoole - the extra loops do seem to matter. Try to execute the code which has been attached. This may not be exactly related to the problem, but then the question is - what is causing process to run out of memory ?

Comment: @tbone - yeah. I am the DBA who has been asked to troubleshoot this code. And IMHO, executing large DML across link does not makes sense. But this is a legacy code which now needs to be run on a very large dataset.

Comment: is this running on Windows or Linux?  How much swap?  Hopefully nobody was messing with _pga_max_size (which, say, if set to 2G, would allow way too much memory for processes (esp with parallel processing on a busy system) and possibly lead to ora-04030).  But I'm a developer, experienced DBAs on SO can chime in...

Comment: Well they add execution time of course - quite a bit in this case, as you'd expect from executing a loop millions of times, even if the delete itself doesn't do any real work. My 'do they matter' was about the memory issue really. And not sure how to tell. Your code is missing an exit condition, but with that added I haven't seen it generate a memory issue. May be significantly different set-ups of course. Can you tell if the memory exception is being thrown by the local or remote DB?

Comment: @tbone - this was running on Linux. The PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET is set to 1.5 gB. This is a POC ( proof of concept ) setup and there are no other processes which can mess up memory. The SWAP is set to 16gb. The total memory on both source and target is 8GB.

Comment: @AlexPoole - the memory exception is being thrown by local system.

Comment: Have you tried running it on the actual dst instance rather than over a db link?

Comment: @tbone - I executed the script on another system and - the problem was indeed with PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET !!. But after fixing PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET, I see session using up huge amount of memory if I keep the "wide gap" between the IDs. I see that the session used up 900 mb of memory and never finishes. But if there is no "wide gap" ( that is remove two inserts ) between the IDs, then not only my program finishes in few seconds - it uses almost no memory. Question is - why such a simple piece of code use up so much memory ? especially when 99.9999% of iterations loops are not doing anything ?

Comment: My guess would be that you probably wouldn't see this issue if it weren't for the db links.  Probably the work Oracle does during two phase commit when running across links.  If you must run across db links, I can suggest an alternative to incrementing the ids by 1mm and hoping for a hit.  I'll post it tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: @tbone - I have added standalone code which can be executed completely locally. But the problem remains. The PGA code almost never completes, even when there is index. And the PGA usage is still very high.

Comment: How many terations a for loop has done until ORA-0430 has appeared ? What is your DBMS version ?

Comment: Is there any reason why the procedure couldn't be placed in the remote db? Then you could call it from the local database but the work would be done on the remote database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is not an answer, but it's too large to fit in a comment, so here we are!*

There's no need for the dynamic sql. If I were you, I'd rewrite this as:

```
create or replace procedure batch_del as
  l_min_val         integer;
  l_max_val         integer;
  l_begin           integer;
  l_end             integer;
  l_rows_to_process number := 100000;
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  select min(id),
         max(id),
         count(*)
  into   l_min_val,
         l_max_val,
         l_cnt_dst
  from   test1@dst;

  l_begin := l_min_val;

  while l_begin < l_max_val
  loop
    begin
      l_end := l_begin + l_rows_to_process;

      delete from test1@dst
      where  id >= l_begin
      and    id < l_end;

      dbms_output.put_line('rows deleted: '||sql%rowcount);

      commit;
    exception
      when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('error : ' || sqlcode);
    end;

    l_begin := l_begin + l_rows_to_process;

  end loop;
end;
/
```

Alternatively, if you've got non-consecutive id's, perhaps this would be more performant for you:

```
create or replace procedure batch_del as
  type type_id_array is table of number index by pls_integer;
  l_min_id_array     type_id_array;
  l_max_id_array     type_id_array;
  l_rows_to_process  number := 10000;
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin

  select min(id) min_id,
         max(id) max_id bulk collect
  into   l_min_id_array,
         l_max_id_array
  from   (select --/*+ driving_site(t1) */
                 id,
                 ceil((row_number() over(order by id)) / l_rows_to_process) grp
          from   test1 t1)
  group  by grp
  order  by grp;

  for i in l_min_id_array.first..l_min_id_array.last
  loop
    begin
      delete from test1
      where  id between l_min_id_array(i) and l_max_id_array(i);

      dbms_output.put_line('rows deleted in loop '||i||': '||sql%rowcount);

      commit;
    exception
      when others then
        -- i hope there is some better way of logging an error in your
        -- production db; e.g. a separate procedure writing to a log table.
        dbms_output.put_line('error in loop '||i||': ' || sqlcode);
    end;
  end loop;
end batch_del;
/
```

Comment: @krokodilko - I removed the DBMS_OUTPUT statements and that bought down PGA usage dramatically.  To answer your earlier question  - this is Oracle 11.2.0.4 standard edition and the message started appearing after approx 60 million iterations which equates to 1.5 Gb ( 60,000,000 * 25 bytes per line of DBMS_OUTPUT ).

Comment: I will try your solution on non-consecutive IDs soon and post results.

Comment: Remove the dbms_outputs as appropriate

Comment: I used the solution for non-consecutive IDs and it worked !!. Since the number of loops in such case are reduced a lot - the chances of DBMS_OUTPUT overflowing the output buffer too are reduced. But point well taken  - no reason to have millions of lines of logging.

Comment: How do I mark more than one answer as the one which solved my problem ?

Comment: You can't; you should be able to upvote answers you've found helpful, though.

Answer (score 3):

You are using DMS_Output in your procedure:

```
dbms_output.put_line ( 'Rows Processed : ' || l_cnt );
....
dbms_output.put_line ( 'Rows Processed So Far : ' || l_tot_cnt );
```

Each of the above calls produces a string roughly 25 characters long (~25 bytes).

The `PUT_LINE` prodcedure does not print a message "online" on the console, but rather it places all messages into a memory buffer, please see a note in the documentation: [DBMS_OUTPUT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS67304)

> **Note:** 
> Messages sent using DBMS_OUTPUT are not actually sent until the
>   sending subprogram or trigger completes. **There is no mechanism to
>   flush output during the execution of a procedure.**
>   ....
>   ....
>   **Rules and Limits**
>   The maximum line size is 32767 bytes.
>   
>   The default buffer size is 20000 bytes. The minimum size is 2000 bytes and **the maximum is unlimited.**

You wrote in the question:

> it will take almost 50,000,000,000 iterations

It is very easy to estimate a memory size required for storing DBMS_Output messages, 
just: 2 messagess, each 25 bytes, 50,000,000,000 iterations

```
2 * 25 * 50,000,000,000 = 2 500 000 000 000 bytes
```

It seems you need about 2 500 Gigabytes (~2,5 terabytes) memory to store all messaged from your procedure. PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET = 1.5 gB is definitely too low.

---

Just remove `DBMS_Output` from your code, no one (any human being) is able to read 50~100 billion mesagess from the console.
If you want to monitor the procedure, use [DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_appinf.htm#ARPLS65237), you can store a message up to 64 characters, an then query against V$SESSION view to retrieve last message.

Comment: wow, didn't think dbms_output was being used in the script, but I see the updated post.  Definitely don't want it in production code, especially looping like this.  Good catch! (logging commit points to a log table via autonomous procedure is what I'd do)

Comment: select min(id) min_id, max(id) max_id bulk collect  into l_min_id_array,
         l_max_id_array
        from   (select --/*+ driving_site(t1) */
                 id, ceil((row_number() over(order by id)) / l_rows_to_process) 
            grp from   test1 t1)
            group  by grp
            order  by grp; When I try above as part of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, I get ORA-03001 Unimplemented feature

Answer (score 0):

To make @boneist answer more flexible, one can use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE as follows:

```
loop
.....
  str := 'select min(id) min_id, max(id) max_id l_min_id_array, 
           l_max_id_array from (select id, ceil((row_number() over(order by 
           id)) / l_rows_to_process) grp from test1 t1) group by grp order 
           by grp';

  execute immediate str bulk collect into l_min_id_array, l_max_id_array;
  ....
 end loop;
```